# Find elements in list that is between elements with that have the same value using a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Good day.
I have a list that looks like this :

```
my_list = [
'BENEFICIAR',
'PROFIL COMPANIE',
'MONITORIZEAZĂ',
 'DELIA',     
 'Administrator',
 'Alexandros',
 'Administrator',
 'Andreas',
 'Administrator',
 'BENEFICIAR',
 'MONITORIZEAZĂ',
 'LEBADA',
 'Mobil: 0721',
 'Email: sales@lebada.com',
 '',
 'BENEFICIAR',
 'PROFIL',
 'MONITORIZEAZĂ',
 'AVA',
 'Email: office@ava.com',
 'Site: ',
 'Adresa: ',
 'Oras: ',
 'Judet: ',
 'Cifra afaceri:',
 'Numar angajati: ',
 'Profit: ',
 'CUI: ',     
 'Tel:']
```

My code looks like this:

```
n=-1
lista_beneficiar_mail={}
for lines in my_list:
  n += 1
  if lines == "MONITORIZEAZĂ":
    ben = line[n+1]        
    for lines in my_list[n+1:]:
        if lines.startswith('Email'):
            mail=lines
        else:
            continue
        if lines == "MONITORIZEAZĂ":
            break
    lista_beneficiar_mail[ben]=mail
```

The idea is that from that list I need to create a dict that has as keys the n+1 indexed value from 'MONITORIZEAZA' and the value of the keys the first email that comes after.

So...this does not seem to work, I know I am doing something wrong and I have reached a wall where my mind does not know what to search what to test anymore. I know it's a easy answer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the first instance of an email after any `'key_value'` we can just check for the first email after it using a bool to check, we can then use the bool to check whether that `key_value` has found it's email.

```
my_list = [
    'BENEFICIAR',
    'PROFIL COMPANIE',
    'MONITORIZEAZĂ',
     'DELIA',     
     'Administrator',
     'Alexandros',
     'Administrator',
     'Andreas',
     'Administrator',
     'BENEFICIAR',
     'MONITORIZEAZĂ',
     'LEBADA',
     'Mobil: 0721',
     'Email: sales@lebada.com',
     '',
     'BENEFICIAR',
     'PROFIL',
     'MONITORIZEAZĂ',
     'AVA',
     'Email: office@ava.com',
     'Site: ',
     'Adresa: ',
     'Oras: ',
     'Judet: ',
     'Cifra afaceri:',
     'Numar angajati: ',
     'Profit: ',
     'CUI: ',     
     'Tel:']
     
my_dict = {}
ben = ""
found = True #the variable that we use to check
for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if (not found and my_list[i].startswith("Email:")): #if we haven't found the last key_value's email and we got a match
            found = True # We found it
            my_dict[ben] = my_list[i]
        if (my_list[i] == "MONITORIZEAZĂ"):
            ben = my_list[i+1]
            found = False # New counter if we haven't found the it
```

This is also more efficient as we only loop through the list once whereas your other approach meant that we check some cases multiple times.

Comment: hi, thanks thanks for the comment, realized that i needed something more than that, and edited my question , took me longer than i expected and enough time for you to answer my initial question, sorry

Comment: what kind of dictionary are you looking for, could you please give the expected result, thanks

Comment: lista_beneficiar_mail={
'DELIA': 'Email: sales@lebada.com';
'AVA':'Email: office@ava.com'
}
This is how the dict should look.

Comment: @chertionut does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using a while loop. This way you aren't repeating elements you already looped on them.
Like that:

```
lista_beneficiar_mail={}
n=0
while n < len(my_list):
  if my_list[n] == "MONITORIZEAZĂ":
    ben = my_list[n+1]
    mail = ''
    for i in range(n+1, len(my_list)):
      if my_list[i].startswith('Email'):
        mail=my_list[i]
        n = i
        break
    if mail: #in case there is no email in the list you shouldn't add it
      lista_beneficiar_mail[ben]=mail
  n+= 1
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment, realized that I needed something more than that, and edited my question , took me longer than I expected and enough time for you to answer my initial question, sorry.